# What is the big O notation of this function

Tags: python, big-o

```
 result = 0
 i = 0
 while i < 2**n:
      result = result + i
      i += 1
 # end while
```

I'm assuming O(2^n). Python code.

Comment: I'm not into Python; does `2**n` mean `2^n`? If so, the running time is `O(2^n)`.

Comment: yes, it is 2^n as @Codor says. if you are interested how it is computed, take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4852666/4481312

Comment: @melpomene: `2**n` requires one *shift*: `2**n` == `1 << n`; `n` doesn't change within the loop so we might expect `2**n` will *not* be recomputed

Comment: @melpomene "Is Python smart enough to [optimize this]?" -> So, is it? You asserted that `2**n` was recomputed at every iteration, so you seem to know about this subject. Though I know that `while i < some_function(n)` would make `some_function(n)` be re-evaluated at every iteration, I am not sure it is the same with `2**n`, since it uses a built-in. I genuinely wonder if Python does this optimization.

Comment: @melpomene That doesn't factor into the O notation. What if the code does a `sleep(1)` in every loop iteration? *That's just how long one loop takes.* That's not what O is expressing. O is expressing the *complexity*, not the absolute running time.

Comment: @deceze You're right. I wasn't thinking clearly. I retract all of my comments.

Comment: For the record, in all existing versions of CPython, (1) `2**n` *is* recomputed on every iteration, and (2) it is not computed by doing `1 << n`. The latter would be [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60325865/12299000) for large n.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code's time complexity is `O(2^n log n)` because you are computing `2^n`, for `2^n` times.
`a^b` can compute in `O(log b)` for [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and I think the exponential algorithm in python is `O(log n)` algorithm.
So, the time complexity is `O(2^n log n)`.

Comment: you're right that the exponentiation may take nontrivial time  (perhaps it's logarithmic, quite possibly a constant time bit shift) but the overall complexity class is best served as basic as possible, in this case `O(2^n * log n) == O(2^n)`. We try not to care about small fish

Comment: @nperson325681 `O(2^n * log n)` is not `O(2^n)`. You don't get to throw away a non-constant *factor* just because the other factor is much bigger; apply the definition of big O, and you'll see there is no constant c such that `2^n * c > 2^n * log n` for sufficiently large n, because `log n` is not bounded by a constant.

Comment: By the way, computing 2^n takes at least O(n) time simply because the result requires at least n+1 bits to represent, and you can't output n+1 bits in under O(n) time.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is O(2<sup>n</sup> × n).

The reason is that numbers of size 2<sup>O(n)</sup> take O(n) bits to represent as `int` objects. If the result of an arithmetic operation takes O(n) bits then it can't be done in less than O(n) time, because Python's `int` objects are immutable.

So:

- The addition `result = result + i` takes O(n) time because `result` uses O(n) bits.
- The addition `i += 1` takes O(n) time, because `i` uses O(n) bits.
- It also takes O(n) time to compute `2**n`, for the same reason: the result of this operation uses O(n) bits. The exponentiation algorithm only does O(log n) multiplications, but the time is dominated by the last multiplication, which is like 2<sup>n/2</sup> * 2<sup>n/2</sup>.
- And of course, the comparison `i < 2**n` takes O(n) time because both numbers use O(n) bits.

So, the loop iterates O(2<sup>n</sup>) times, and it does O(n) work on each iteration, hence the result.

Comment: Based on some benchmarks, I think `2**n` isn't O(n) but is *worse*. And it's not clear why 2^(n/2) * 2^(n/2) is O(n). It's a multiplication of two (n/2+1)-bit numbers. At least the naive way from school would take O(n^2) for that.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I wasn't able to find a reference, so I benchmarked up to n = 10^10 and it seemed to be either O(n) or O(n log n) - the best-fit curve has a s.d. of about 5-6% either way, which is less than the error on the individual measurements - and I can't think of a good reason that O(n log n) should be right. It sure doesn't look like O(n^2). Here's up to 10^9 and 10^10 on Python 3.6.2 respectively: https://i.imgur.com/4gZRKXV.png https://i.imgur.com/BgT76Wk.png

Comment: I think multiplication [uses Karatsuba](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/02673352b5db6ca4d3dc804965facbedfe66425d/Objects/longobject.c#L3657). And for *random* large ints I do observe Karatsuba's O(n^1.58). I guess the factor being a power of 2 happens to make that faster because the lower half of a factor is always zero. Not yet sure how much faster.