# Reducing the complexity/computation time for a basic graph formula

Tags: python, math, time-complexity, graph-theory

I tried to use the basic formula (got it from another SO question),
for calculating the max number of different edge sets, for `n` vertices:

```
2**(n*(n-1)/2)
```

but it's good only for small range of numbers - then it gets too complex.

Is there a way to improve this formula/reduce the complexity?

Comment: Do you really need such large numbers? What are you going to do with them?

Comment: *"Too complex"?* It's a very simple formula.

Comment: What do you mean by "it gets too complex" ? Do you just mean "too large" ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way to speed this up quite considerably: `2 ** x` is always equal to `1 << x`, so long as `x` is a non-negative integer; but the latter is hundreds of times faster, because it's just [shifting bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) rather than doing arithmetic.

```py
>>> def slow(n):
...     return 2 ** (n * (n-1) // 2)
... 
>>> def fast(n):
...     return 1 << (n * (n-1) // 2)
... 
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda: slow(1000), number=1000)
1.5656050549987413
>>> timeit(lambda: fast(1000), number=1000)
0.005352460000722203
```

Comment: dear friend, thanks for your fast reply. can you elaborate please? I am noob so the sign << is new to me and I didnt catch the difference between the two options :)

Comment: If you have a binary number, say `0000 0000 0000 0001` and you shift it left the `<<` operator) once, you get `0000 0000 0000 0010`, and doing it again you get `0000 0000 0000 0100` and so on, which, in decimal, are 1, 2, and 4, respectively. This is a way to calculate powers of 2, by taking advantage of the binary system. This is far simpler for a computer to do than to do than explicitly multiplying 2, n times.

Comment: See Wikipedia for an explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

Comment: A shift operator will work, at best, up to $n=11$ (64 bits machine).

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is not true; Python's integers are unbounded, so e.g. `1 << 100` works just fine and gives `1267650600228229401496703205376`, which is the same as `2 ** 100`.

Comment: @kaya3: when I say 64 bits machine, I am referring to the native instruction, obviously.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Python's `<<` operator is not a native instruction.

Comment: so how do I actually implement this solution? just use: return 1 << (n * (n-1) // 2) and it will yield the result?

Comment: @Om3gaSupr3m3 ...you write `1 << (n * (n-1) // 2)`.

Comment: @kaya3: hence my remark about the machine bitness.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, the question is about Python, I wrote an answer about how the problem can be solved in Python using a shift operator; you wrote that a shift operator wouldn't work above n=11, which is wrong, and then you said you meant it about native instructions, which is irrelevant to Python. If you knew it was irrelevant to Python then I really don't understand what you are trying to add with your comment; yes, if you write this in a different language with a different datatype that doesn't support large integers, then you won't be able to represent large integers using that datatype.